# Instagram Fetch E-Mail (2019 Fix?)

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, instagram

Few hours ago, Instagram patched a way to see business accounts' E-Mail address. Is there a good API or any other way to fetch business account E-Mail?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the same :( not sure if it's an intended change or just a bug (they might already be rolling out the new business hashtag features, so maybe it's due to that).